# android build source errors

Tags: android, build-process, linux-kernel, compiler-errors, ubuntu-10.04

i have ubuntu installed on the lenovo s10e netbook. I am not sure if this is related to the issue. I am new to source builds so I would appreciate some direction. I followed instructions on cyanogen's wiki (http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php/Building_from_source)

I am stuck on the last step of 'Building CyanogenMod' after starting the build process.

```
$make -j4
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=AOSP
TARGET_PRODUCT=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
============================================
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/apicheck.jar
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/clearsilver.jar
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/droiddoc.jar
host SharedLib: libneo_cgi (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libneo_cgi.so)
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libneo_cgi.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'll double this question. Using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Same problem.

Comment: Ubunutu Netbook Edition - latest i.e. ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386 
I am running it on a lenovo s10e with intel atom processor N270 / 1.6 GHz
Cache Memory: 512 KB, L2 cache
RAM: 512 MB (installed) / 1.5 GB (max), DDR2 SDRAM, 667 MHz, PC2-5300 ( provided memory is soldered )
Hard Drive: 80 GB, Serial ATA-150, 5400 rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question, but in case anybody looks for it, here is what I found: if you are running 64-bit ubuntu, the correct library is lib32z1-dev, so:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

"-lz" implies that the compiler is trying to link against some library "libz.{a,so}". I searched the packages.ubuntu.com website to find the package it is located in:
zlib1g-dev

Install the package:
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

And you should be able to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your operating system is 64-bit and you need a 32-bit libz. Try
`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`.